# Is there a way to create a UIImage in Swift that will animate only once?

Tags: swift, animation, uiimage

I am trying to create an animated image to use in my iPhone app. I need this animation to play only once. I have found how to do it with an UIImageView, but I need to use a UIImage only for this project, meaning the code for animation should come from the UIImage itself, not from the UIImageView. I know how to create the animated UIImage using animatedImagewithImages function, but it makes the animation loop forever. Is there any way to restrict it to only one?

Just to be clear, I am not looking for a solution involving UIImageView repeatCount, the UIImage itself needs to be able to stop its animation.

Comment: What do you mean by "play"? a UIImage is static

Comment: You can create animated UIImages and put them in UIImageViews, the animation will play without having to ask anything from the imageView.

Comment: ah sorry, missed that part. Hate to break it to you, but that's not intention of that API and anything you might be able to get working will be a hack that might break. If you want to control the animation there are other options.

Comment: You could subclass UIImage and set up an animation to run whenever the subclass is configured.

Comment: so you mean setting up the animation in the init()?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just create the image with an Array that has the first N-1 frames, followed by a large number of duplicates of the last frame? For example, say you've got 30 frames, and you want 1 second of video that holds for a minute at the end. Make an array with the first 29 frames, followed by 1801 copies of the last frame. Set the duration to 61 seconds, and there you have it.

This won't pause forever, but you can make it arbitrarily-long.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but wouldn't it be very memory-heavy?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it, but NSImage instances can share the same NSImageRep (which is the actual bitmap data). I expect that multiple "copies" of the same frame won't use any significant amount of memory.

Comment: A quick test in the simulator seems to bear this out. 1000 frames of the same image doesn't take up much more memory than 10 frames (maybe about 1MB more).

Comment: OK I'm going to try that. Just a note: the animation is comprised of one image surrounded by two black images. Since the idea is to show the image only once, would it be possible to deallocate the central image and just keep one of the black images right after the first loop?

Comment: To be more precise, I don't care if the first or last frame remain; I have images with numbers "1", "2" and "3", would it be possible to deallocate the "two" after the first loop?